# How can I interrupt Callables in an AsyncTask when the AsyncTask.cancel() method is invoked?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, interrupt, executorservice

My Activity has an `AsyncTask` whose `doInBackground` method you can see below. I have to make multiple search request to multiple servers and in order to speed up the execution I've used Java's `ExecutorService` to make concurrent requests.

This works fine but I'd like my `AsyncTask` to stop whatever it is doing and quit, if I call the `AsyncTask.cancel();` method with `true` as the `mayInterruptIfRunning` parameter. This is useful in situations where I need to stop the task when my `Activity` exits e.g. the "Back" button is pressed.

I've read that calling the `cancel()` method of the `AsyncTask` will prevent the `onPostExecute` method from being invoked, but the `doInBackground` will run until it is finished.

Is there a way, I could interrupt my `Callables` and force them to stop whatever it is they are doing and stop the `AsyncTask`.

I have posted an abridged version of my code here for brevity, but I have a bunch of a `Callables`, not just one.

Thanks.

```
  protected ArrayList<Result> doInBackground(final String... strQuery) {

      ArrayList<Result> objResults = new ArrayList<Result>();
      ExecutorService esrExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
      Set<Callable<ArrayList<Result>>> setCallables = new HashSet<Callable<ArrayList<Result>>>();

      setCallables.add(new Callable<ArrayList<Result>>() {

          public ArrayList<Result> call() throws Exception {

              try {

                  MySearcher objSearcher = new MySearcher(Finder.this.objContext);
                  ArrayList<Result> objResults = new ArrayList<Result>();

                  objResults = objSearcher.doSearch(strQuery[0]);

                  return objResults;

              } catch (Indexer.LoginException e) {
                  return null;
              }

              return null;

          }

      });


      List<Future<ArrayList<Result>>> lstFutures;

      try {

          lstFutures = esrExecutor.invokeAll(setCallables);

          for(Future<ArrayList<Result>> futFuture : lstFutures){
              if (futFuture.get().isEmpty() == false)
                  objResults.addAll(futFuture.get());
          }

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      esrExecutor.shutdown();

      return objResults;

  }
```

Comment: I think `futFuture.get()` is going to block the UI, right?

Comment: @Lalit Poptani: Is that it? I haven't yet checked but that would seem logical that the `futFuture.get()` blocks.

Comment: yeah I am just watching a video for Callable & Future on youtube and it says that I will block UI until the task gets completed. Here [it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnbWFV4b7M4)

Comment: I would insist to use AsyncTask and return value from there. You can check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453385/is-it-possible-to-get-results-of-asynctask-as-an-arraylist-hashmap/12453438#12453438)

Answer (score 3):

I think that one solution would be to check for [`isCancelled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29) regularly in your `doInBackground()` method to check if the `AsyncTask` was cancelled and if you need to stop what you are doing earlier.

Comment: Where should this be placed? It seems that the `Callables` aren't executed until the `ExecutorService.invokeAll` method is called. Right after that comes the loop on which I'm fetching the results from the `Callables` and appending to my `List`. I'm confused because I can't see any code where I iterate and constantly wait for the `Callables` to complete. This is a bunch of `Callables` invoked from another thread, `AsyncTask`, invoked from yet another thread, `Acitivity`. I would need to send an interrupt even to the `Callables` so that the interrupt propagates through the whole chain, but how?

Comment: You can check when iterating over the list of `Future`. If the AsyncTask has been cancelled, then you will call `cancel()` on each futures break the loop, shutdown the `ExecutorService` and return `null`/`Collections.emptyList()`.

Comment: Yes. That could work but wouldn't that still allow one iteration of the loop? It wouldn't be a "true" interrupt. What I'd like to accomplish is to shutdown the `ExecutorService` by calling `ExecutorService.shutdown()` the moment the `AsyncTask.cancel` method is called and kill all the threads (`Callables`) of the `ExecutorService` immediately. Is this even possible?

Comment: Normally if you call `cancel(true)` on the asynTask then the `isCancelled()` method should directly respond `true`. So whether you will make an iteration of the loop or not depends on what time is elapsed between the `doInBackground` starts and the cancel method is called. I don't know a way to effectively shutdown the `ExecutorService` upon call to `cancel` on `AsyncTask`. Checking in the `doInBackground` is what I would do

Answer (score 1):

Here is the place you iterate and wait:

```
   for(Future<ArrayList<Result>> futFuture : lstFutures){
          if (futFuture.get().isEmpty() == false)
              objResults.addAll(futFuture.get());
      }
```

the `get()` method for Future, `Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.`
 you can check `isCancelled()`  like this,

```
       for(Future<ArrayList<Result>> futFuture : lstFutures){
           if(isCancelled())
              break;
           else if (futFuture.get().isEmpty() == false)
              objResults.addAll(futFuture.get());
      }
      if(isCancelled())esrExecutor.shutdownNow();
```

Comment: @Alex, suggested the same thing below. Have a look my comment as why I feel that this wouldn't be the implementation for a "true" interrupt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489636/how-can-i-interrupt-callables-in-an-asynctask-when-the-asynctask-cancel-method#comment16806465_12489792

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if for example `doSearch` has a loop you could do it manually without the use of `isCancelled` or `cancel`. Your MySearcher class could have the following.

```
//in your MySearcher class
private AtomicBoolean cancelled = false;

public ArrayList<Result> doSearch(...){
    while(notFound && !cancelled.get()){
     // keep searching
    }
}

public void cancel(){
    cancelled.set(true);
}
```

now you can call cancel from anywhere.